# $f(x, y)=exp(-3x)+exp(-y)+5x^2y^2$ initial guess $x^0=0, y^0=0$

Tags: functions, derivatives, numerical-methods, maxima-minima, stationary-point

**Qno:** Find critical points for $f$.

Can anyone help to understand this and how to solve it?

Do I have to use first derivative test or is there any other numerical method to solve this type of problem ?

$$f_x=-3e^{-3x}+10xy^2=0$$

$$f_y=-e^{-y}+10x^2y=0$$

What will be such $x, y$ to satisfy above equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are supposed to know Lambert function
$$f_y=0\quad \implies \quad y=W\left(\frac{1}{10 x^2}\right)$$ So, it remains to solve for $x$
$$10 \,x\,\Bigg( W\left(\frac{1}{10 x^2}\right)\Bigg)^2-3 e^{-3 x}=0$$

Using graphics, the solutions are close to $0.01$, $0.25$ and $1.67$.

Graphically, the roots are easier to see if you consider the intersections of functions
$$g(x)=-3x+\log(3)$$
$$h(x)=\log(10)+\log(x)+2 \log\Bigg( W\left(\frac{1}{10 x^2}\right)\Bigg)$$

**Edit**

Notice that, if $x$ is "large"
$$\Bigg( W\left(\frac{1}{10 x^2}\right)\Bigg)^2=\frac{1}{100 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ and then
$$\frac{1}{10 x^3}-3 e^{-3 x}=0 \quad \implies \quad x=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{30}}\right)\sim 1.61$$

Answer (score 0):

The critical points of $f$ occur where the gradient $\nabla f$ vanishes. This gives a system of two equations in $x,y$.

Comment: But what is benefit of initial guess here?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that part. It looks like you might have to solve the system numerically. One approach is to the Newton-Raphson method. I found this link to be helpful: https://engcourses-uofa.ca/books/numericalanalysis/nonlinear-systems-of-equations/newton-raphson-method/

Taking an initial guess of (x,y)=(0,0), my homespun Newton-Raphson code converged to the critical point near (0.25,0.75) within 3 iterations. Actually, if you plot $f_x,f_y$ in Desmos or whatnot, you'll see there's a second critical point near (1.66,0.03). You can find this too by adjusting the initial guess.

Comment: @CW279. It seems that you missed a very small root.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Comment: $(x_1, x_2)=(0.01, 0.05)$ is very small root.